# How do the eigenpairs of a matrix change after some matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am interested to know if there is a way to find the eigenpairs of matrix $AT$ or $TA$ from $A$, where $A$ is an arbitrary matrix and $T$ is some transform matrix.

**Edit**
$$AV = \lambda V$$
$$(TA)V_1 = \lambda_1 V_1$$
$$(AT)V_2 = \lambda_2 V_2$$

Is there a relation between $V,V_1,V_2$ using $T$?

Comment: No, in general both the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors change except in some particular cases such as when $T$ is diagonal matrix, or when $T$ has the same eigenvectors of $A$, in which cases the eigenvalues may change while the eigenvectors remain the same.

Comment: Consider the case of a nonsingular matrix $A$ and $T=A^{-1}$. Consider also the case of $T=JA^{-1}$ where $J$ is any Jordan block.

Comment: What is "the transform matrix"? Any arbitrary matrix? Or do you mean one that corresponds to change of basis?

Comment: Your reasoning does not hold, $(TA)v = \lambda (Tv)$ does not mean that $Tv$ is an eigenvector of $TA$.

Comment: @YiFan What happens if $T$ is a special matrix?

Comment: If $T$ corresponds to some change of basis, then the eigenvalues will be unchanged, and the eigenvectors will be transformed by the same change of basis matrix.

Comment: @Paul Yes, I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @YiFan Interesting. This is what I meant. If possible, please provide an example using rotation matrices in 2-D basis (including proof) so I can accept your answer.

Comment: @YiFan, I had another question if you had time. some transforms are in the form of $T^{-1}AT$, or $P^{-1}AT$. how about them?

Comment: Sorry, I think I might have misread the question, my original claim isn't true because $TA$ is not actually the same linear transformation under change of basis. For your second question, it is in fact the case that $TAT^{-1}$ can be thought of as the same linear transformation after a change of coordinates described by $T$. In this case if $Av=\lambda v$ then $TAT^{-1}(Tv) = TAv = \lambda(Tv)$ so $Tv$ is an eigenvector of $TAT^{-1}$. This is not true for $TA$ because e.g. take $A$ the identity and $T$ a rotation of $\mathbb R^2$, which has no eigenvectors. Not sure what $P$ is supposed to be.

Comment: I could expand this into an answer if you wish. Are you interested in the general case or just for rotations of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @YiFan These are all very interesting. yes please just stick to $\mathbb R^2$ so I can better understand. I would appreciate if you could explain anything related in answer. and about rotation, I had the idea that since only angle is sufficient to describe eigenvectors (if normalized), rotation would transform them to any vectors.

Comment: @KBS What happens when $T$ is diagonal (with non identical entries)?

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi To answer those questions, you can just pick up examples. But, in general everything changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix multiplication essentially corresponds to composing linear transformations on some vector space. For this reason, there is no reason to expect that there would be a nice relationship between eigenvectors and eigenvalues after the transformation. For example, let $A,T\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ where $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}, T=R_\theta=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
so $A$ is the identity, and $R_\theta$ is rotation counterclockwise by angle $\theta$. Now, if $\theta$ is a generic angle like, say, $\pi/3$, then $T$ has no eigenvectors, because everything is rotated and nothing is fixed in direction. This shows we cannot have some kind of relation between the eigenvectors of $A$ and $TA$, nor between $A$ and $AT$, because eigenvectors might not even exist in the first place!

On the other hand, there is something meaningful to be said about $TAT^{-1}$. Notice that, algebraically, $TAT^{-1}(Tv)=TAv = T\lambda v = \lambda(Tv)$ given any eigenvector $Av=\lambda v$. Thus the eigenvectors are transformed by $T$, and eigenvalues remain fixed. This is conceptually because any expression of the type $TAT^{-1}$ can be interpreted as a change of basis according to $T$, and $Tv$ is simply the expression for the vector in terms of the new coordinates. This holds whenever $T$ is invertible.